# css horizontal sub menu without fixed width

Tags: css, html, menu, navigation

my horizontal navigation menu is not rendered the same in chrome and firefox/ie.

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WLhvb/3/

Is there a way to have it look equal (like in the chrome browser), without setting a fixed width to `<ul class="level_2">`?

visual comparison
[image]

Comment: Which chrome version are you using?

Comment: i'm using SRWare Iron as version 25.0.1400.0 (185000) and version 26.0.1450.0 (190000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WLhvb/8/

The key was to set the positioning of the `ul.level_2` to `position: static;` and getting rid of the `float: left`.